# Can a segmentation fault cause a program to hang?

Tags: c++

I thought segmentation fault only causes crashes. But when I run my c++ program (on windows with mingw compiler) it hangs. But when I run it in gdb it says segmentation fault.

Comment: if you have undefined behavior, it may not error in the same way each time.

Comment: Expanding on what Nei Kirk said:  The seg fault would not cause your program to hang, but the same memory clobber bug that caused the seg fault might instead cause a hang when the program is loaded into memory slightly differently (so a different relative address is clobbered).

Comment: Also, some debuggers may intentionally modify the contents of uninitialized memory, so that use of an uninitialized pointer is much more likely to seg fault, when it might cause other behavior (including hanging) without that interference by the debugger.

Comment: I think the way to go forward will be to fix the seg fault, fix all the warning in your code and then see that your program still hangs.

Comment: @JSF You should add those comments to your answer, because currently it does not address the original question.

Comment: Does your program install a specific signal handler that catches SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 0):

That should be much easier to solve than the reverse:  If it seg faulted without the debugger but hangs with the debugger, that can be tricky to debug.  Anything that seg faults with a debugger gives you a very easy way (get a backtrace after it seg faults) to get the direct cause of the seg fault, which usually (but not always) directly indicates the bug.

For your title question, you will likely discover the specific situation after you discover the cause of your seg fault.  But in theory, it is possible but unlikely:  In some environments some segfaults can be caught by try/catch and your code could be structured so catching such a fault puts the program in an infinite loop.  More likely the same bug that causes a seg fault in the debugger causes a hang outside the debugger.  Likely the debugger loads the program, its stack and/or its command line arguments at slightly different virtual addresses.  Some random memory clobber might trigger a hang for one load location and seg fault for another.  Alternately, some debuggers intentionally modify uninitialized memory,  so that use of an uninitialized pointer is much more likely to seg fault, when it might cause other behavior (including hanging) without that interference by the debugger.